# permission denied (publickey) - AWS EC2

Tags: django, macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I am trying to get a Django app running on Amazon EC2. I currently have my .pem file saved in the root of my Django project.

When I try this

```
chmod 600 oby.pem
ssh -i oby.pem ubuntu@52.0.215.90
```

in my mac terminal, I receive this error: `Permission denied (publickey).`

- To begin, am I saving the my `oby.pem` file in the right location? If not, where should it go?
- Furthermore, what are the necessary steps to correctly set up the ssh key?

Thank you!

Comment: login aws mgmt console, and choice the ec2 instance, can you see the `Key pair name`,  looks when you create the instance, you didn't apply it.

Comment: I usually put keys in ~/.ssh,

With that in mind, what happens when you do `ssh -vvv -i  oby.pem ubuntu@52.0.215.90`

Comment: @fiacre it says "Permission denied (publickey)". I also moved my key into !/.ssh and the same thing happened. Any ideas?

Comment: @BMW in my console I have the key name listed. Is there a way to apply it through terminal? I'm not exactly sure what you mean, so sorry if my question doesn't make sense.

Comment: can you try `ssh -i oby.pem root@52.0.215.90` ?